# How to create Html email for Kunena

Tags: kunena

I have a joomla site with Kunena installed on it. My users are not happy with the layout of the email sent to them from the forum.

Here is part of the code that is responsible for creating this email:

```
protected function createEmailBody($subscription, $subject, $url, $message, $once) {
    $config = KunenaFactory::getConfig();
    if ($subscription) {
        $msg1 = $this->get ( 'parent' ) ? JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION1' ) : JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION1_CAT' );
        $msg2 = $this->get ( 'parent' ) ? JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION2' ) : JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION2_CAT' );
    } else {
        $msg1 = JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_MOD1' );
        $msg2 = JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_MOD2' );
    }

    $msg = $msg1 . " " . $config->board_title . "\n\n";
    // DO NOT REMOVE EXTRA SPACE, JMailHelper::cleanBody() removes "Subject:" from the message body
    $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_MESSAGE_SUBJECT' ) . " : " . $subject . "\n";
    $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_CATEGORY' ) . " : " . $this->getCategory()->name . "\n";
    $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_VIEW_POSTED' ) . " : " . $this->getAuthor()->getName('???', false) . "\n\n";
    $msg .= "URL : $url\n\n";
    if ($config->mailfull == 1) {
        $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_MESSAGE' ) . " :\n-----\n";
        $msg .= $message;
        $msg .= "\n-----\n\n";
    }
    $msg .= $msg2 . "\n";
    if ($subscription && $once) {
        if ($this->parent) {
            $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_MORE_READ' ) . "\n";
        } else {
            $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_MORE_SUBSCRIBE' ) . "\n";
        }
    }
    $msg .= "\n";
    $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION3' ) . "\n";
    return JMailHelper::cleanBody ( $msg );
}
```

So I decided to add an image as of the logo from my site to it at the bottom like this:

```
$msg .= ('<img src="http://mysite.me.ke/templates/jsn_nuru_free/images/colors/red/logo.png" width="100"/>');
```

butwhen the email was sent it returned the same thing I gave it

```
 <img src="http://mysite.me.ke/templates/jsn_nuru_free/images/colors/red/logo.png" width="100"/>
```

so I thought I should use htmlspecialchars_decode() php function as in:

```
$msg .= htmlspecialchars_decode('<img src="http://mysite.me.ke/templates/jsn_nuru_free/images/colors/red/logo.png" width="100"/>');
```

But still I got nothing new. Kindly help me out!

Comment: There is an official forum for support http://www.kunena.org/forum/index

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `JUri::root()` when defining the path of your site, like so:

```
$msg .= '<img src="' . JUri::root() . 'templates/jsn_nuru_free/images/colors/red/logo.png" width="100"/>';
```

In addition to this, I've removed the brackets you added outside the image tag as they're not required

Comment: No I didnt ask you to remove anything on my examples because they are right, what is not working right now is the html attributes like <H1>, <b>, <table> all those are not working tell me how html attributes can be passed to an email message

Comment: Lodder is only trying to help you... 
Also, he is right about removing the brackes.
Take a look at how to send html emails here: https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

Comment: @JacksonSiro - Check the revision history and you'll notice I **haven't** touched any of your examples

Answer (score 1):

Hey Jack if you could try using JUri::root() when defining the path of your site, like so:

```
   protected function createEmailBody($subscription, $subject, $url, $message, $once) {
        $config = KunenaFactory::getConfig();
        if ($subscription) {
            $msg1 = $this->get ( 'parent' ) ? JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION1' ) : JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION1_CAT' );
            $msg2 = $this->get ( 'parent' ) ? JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION2' ) : JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION2_CAT' );
        } else {
            $msg1 = JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_MOD1' );
            $msg2 = JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_MOD2' );
        }

        $msg = $msg1 . " " . $config->board_title . "\n\n";
        // DO NOT REMOVE EXTRA SPACE, JMailHelper::cleanBody() removes "Subject:" from the message body
        $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_MESSAGE_SUBJECT' ) . " : " . $subject . "\n";
        $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_CATEGORY' ) . " : " . $this->getCategory()->name . "\n";
        $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_VIEW_POSTED' ) . " : " . $this->getAuthor()->getName('???', false) . "\n\n";
        $msg .= "URL : $url\n\n";
        if ($config->mailfull == 1) {
            $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_MESSAGE' ) . " :\n-----\n";
            $msg .= $message;
            $msg .= "\n-----\n\n";
            $msg .= '<img src="' . JUri::root() . 'templates/jsn_nuru_free/images/colors/red/logo.png" width="100"/>';
        }
        $msg .= $msg2 . "\n";
        if ($subscription && $once) {
            if ($this->parent) {
                $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_MORE_READ' ) . "\n";
            } else {
                $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_MORE_SUBSCRIBE' ) . "\n";
            }
        }
        $msg .= "\n";
        $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_POST_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION3' ) . "\n";
        return JMailHelper::cleanBody ( $msg );
    }
```